# elm-live: Unable to use custom HTML to reference CSS file

Tags: html, css, elm

I am using the elm-live dev server but I do not know how to use an external CSS file.  According to documentation, I can use the following code below, but where do use that snippet of code?  If i use it in the index.html it still gets overwritten on when i save my *.elm files.

Thanks

elm-live states:

```
$ cat <<——— > index.html
  <!doctype html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <body>
    <div></div>
    <script src="elm.js"></script>
    <script>Elm.Main.embed(document.querySelector("div"));</script>
  </body>
———
$ elm-live Main.elm --output=elm.js --open
```

Comment: It works for me.  I guess you should provide info about your environment (OS, versions of node / elm / elm-live, etc).  Also, does elm.js gets created, or only index.html?

Comment: Hi,  I am using Node V 4.1.1, elm 0.17, elm-live 2.5.1.  Only the index.html gets generated.  I paste the above snippet in the index.html file, but it always gets overridden when i save my *.elm files.   Thanks

Comment: what happens if you run elm-make with the same output parameter? does elm.js get created? or index.html.

Comment: It works now, sorry I was not properly interpreting the elm-live instructions.  I was not running  the command `elm-live Main.elm --output=elm.js --open` but just `elm-live Main.elm`

Comment: Great, I'm glad you solved your problem. Consider posting an answer to your question with the details to help others find the solution.